# Chrome account sign in details are out of date

Tags: google-chrome

I have signed into Chrome several times at work and at home, each time providing my two factor authentication code. This seems to work for a while, but next time I check the title bar, there's the warning sign again indicating my sign-in is no longer in sync. I need to sign in again to get rid of this warning indicator.

[image]

[image]

Why does my Chrome sign-in keep getting out of date; why does it keep prompting for my two-factor authentication code despite the fact that I tell it not to prompt again on this device, and how can I correct this?

**Edit:** Other articles have suggested disconnecting and re-connecting my Google account, which I did at the beginning of the weekend, and now it's out of sync again (less than 2 days later).

Comment: This exact thing has been happening to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue, being fixed in next release: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/-YI1zZUdeF4 (See top answer)

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same issue  and retraced my steps on my mobile device and discovered an app that was added to my phone to be the culprit. I had added an internet app that would block all ads. I removed this app and this problem went away

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this problem a couple of days ago.
I followed instruction above plus clearing all local data on device, then signing in again. I noticed there are 2 auto-added extensions, which are Docs and Sheets by Google, I removed them, along with Keep. Then re-adding Keep, close Chrome and re-open. It works fine.